# How to add default value in an existing table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add default value to an existing table, but it is not working at all. I am expecting to see `'NO'` when I add data in my table but it is not happening. I am not sure what is going on or if my syntax is wrong here. Please help. Thanks

```
ALTER TABLE [myTable] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_myTable_FLAG]  DEFAULT ('NO') FOR [FLAG]
```

The datatype for this column is `varchar`.

Comment: Can you show us the insert statement you're using to insert a row?

Comment: First of all, this only applies to **new rows** being added, and it only works if you **don't explicitly** specify a value for that column in your `INSERT` statement. The syntax looks fine - but how are you **inserting** your new rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only new records will get the default.

Test this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST(NAME VARCHAR(5), FLAG VARCHAR(3))
INSERT INTO #TEST (NAME) SELECT 'DAVE'
ALTER TABLE #TEST ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TEST_FLAG]  DEFAULT ('NO') FOR [FLAG]
INSERT INTO #TEST (NAME) SELECT 'MOE'

SELECT * FROM #TEST
```

Old records must be manually updated.